# Cloudinary how to update/edit images in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, cloudinary

I followed the tutorial on cloudinary.com to upload multiple (product) images to cloudinary. It works fine when I add a new product and upload a new image. When I try to edit/update the product, I want it to add the new image to an image array, but I get the error:

[image]

In my development.log:

> Started PATCH "/admin/products/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-04 09:35:12
>   +0200 Processing by Admin::ProductsController#update as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"4UcQNq49uJDpGAFyOxO3w07dhJFpIHkLYn2IqjLar+kWvNCC12c2Hjctq13rDOE476fPpm479fbV25XOr82bIQ==",$
>   ^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (0.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM
>   "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT
>   $2^[[0$   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.6ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[34mSELECT 
>   "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."active" = $1 AND
>   "products"."id" = $   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[35mBEGIN^[[0m 
>   ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (0.5ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[33mUPDATE "products" SET "images"
>   = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "products"."id" = $3^[[0m  [["images",$   ^[[1m^[[35m (2.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1m^[[35mCOMMIT^[[0m Completed 500
>   Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `reject' for
>   "image/upload/v1525416518/t50yzb4cjtdnlyae4zx2.jpg":String):
>
> app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb:29:in `update'

Even if I don't upload a new image file, I still get the error. I think I did something wrong when setting up Cloudinary...

---

Here's my setup:

First I added the gems in my gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave', github:'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'cloudinary'
```

Then I created the cloudinary.yml file where I added my cloud_name, api_key and api_secret.

In my ProductsController I have set images as an array images: []:

```
def update
 @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
   redirect_to admin_products_path
 else
   redirect_to admin_products_path
 end
end

private

 def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :price, :supply, :shipping_amount, :active, :product_number, images: [] )
 end
end
```

In my views, the images file field looks like this:

```
<%= f.file_field :images, type: :file, multiple: true %><br />
```

---

Edit: Another thing I found out is that when I inspect the page, there's a messed up link:

[http://res.cloudinary.com/dzidt5gxk/raw/upload/v1/%5B%22%5B%5C%22image/upload/v1525416518/t50yzb4cjtdnlyae4zx2.jpg_____](http://res.cloudinary.com/dzidt5gxk/image/upload/v1525416534/exhgstwb354t4l6rqvmh.jpg)

What the link should be:
http://res.cloudinary.com/dzidt5gxk/image/upload/v1525416534/exhgstwb354t4l6rqvmh.jpg

In the rails console it also shows that the images array is messed up:

```
<Product id: 3, name: "Ananas", images: "[\"[\\\"image/upload/v1525416518/t50yzb4cjtdnlyae4zx2...", product_number: "342342">]>
```

Comment: Please post log in plain text, not as an image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Carrierwave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads) :

> Also, make sure your upload controller permits the multiple file
> upload attribute, pointing to **an empty array in a hash**. For example:
>
> `params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, {avatars: []})`

Maybe you just need to change your permit params.

Comment: I changed {images: []} but it didn't do anything. I still get the error.

Comment: @Jakeroo actually it's a known and current issue in `cloudinary_gem` ([here](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/issues/266))